# How do we know the wavefunction for particle that is both massless and chargeless?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, quantum-spin

For electron we observe the quantum spins and then plot in Hilbert space, what about photon? How do we determine it's wavefunction since it travels at speed of light and don't carry electric charge?

Comment: Charge isn't necessary for a wavefunction to exist, neutrinos have a wavefunction and also carry no charge.

Comment: By the common understanding, a photon has no wavefunction.